# Trying to Read Edit box inside Custom Dialog... Getting FC

Tags: android

I am trying to read a EditText box and send its contents to another method from within a Custom dialog box. My current code causes a Force Close. The logcat is very vague... however I know the uncaught exception takes place in this method:

```
public void getName(){

         Dialog dialog = new Dialog(main.this);
         dialog.setContentView(R.layout.customdialog);
         dialog.setTitle("New Game");
         dialog.setCancelable(true);
         //there are a lot of settings, for dialog, check them all out!
         final EditText inputBox = new EditText(this);

         //set up text
         final TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
         text.setText("Enter Your Name...");


         //set up button
         final Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.namebutton);
         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             String str = inputBox.getText().toString(); 
             setName(str);
        }
         });
         //now that the dialog is set up, it's time to show it    
         dialog.show();
     }
```

Here is the custom XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
     <TextView android:text="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/nameprompt"></TextView>
     <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:inputType="textPersonName" android:text="Player">
         <requestFocus></requestFocus>
     </EditText>
     <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/namebutton" android:text="Ok" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></Button>
 </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any ideas???

Comment: Can you give us the logcat output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the EditText in your XML for the Dialog's layout... and you're properly using findViewById() to instantiate your TextView...

You need to do the same for the EditText, also use findViewById() to instantiate it.

```
final EditText inputBox = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something is up with the inputBox object. You create it in this method, but I don't see you actually adding to  the layout anywhere. When this method completes, you'll be displaying the dialog box, but the input box won't be displayed anywhere. In fact, I think that inputBox might be garbage collected since there are not references to if around after the getName() method completes. Therefore when you call get input on it, it might be null.

I think what you meant to do was this:

```
final EditText inputBox = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText1)
```